# A variable that indicates who win

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a database where four of its columns are: score_home, score_away, home_id and away_id.

I expect to get a variable whose rows contain the winning ID in each game.

| Index | gRes |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | GB |
| 1 | GB |

For that, I tried with the following code

```
team_f['gRes'] = 0
if team_f['score_home'] > team_f['score_away']:
    team_f['gRes'] = team_f['home_id']
else:
    team_f['gRes'] = team_f['away_id']
```

and i get the following error

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Could you suggest how to correct the error or, failing that, any alternatives to build the variable?

Comment: what about tied games with level score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if the score are tied?
you'll have three conditions, and np.Select helps

```
# define a list of conditions, and corresponding list of values, 
# when condition is true, 
# and default value as a third attribute

df['gRes'] = np.select([team_f['score_home'] > team_f['score_away'], #cond 1
                       team_f['score_home'] < team_f['score_away']   #cond 2
                       ],
                       [team_f['home_id'],  # cond1 true
                        team_f['away_id']], # cond2 true
                       'drawn'              # default, game tied
                      )
```

PS: if you share a data(preferably as a code) or text, I'd be able to share the result

Answer (score 0):

This is ambiguous because of how you compare the two columns.

Try `np.where`

```
team_f['gRes'] = np.where(team_f['score_home'] > team_f['score_away'], team_f["home_id"], team_f["away_id"])
```

Please include a minimal example of your data if that does not work.

Edit: If draws are possible, np.select is preferred. (See Naveed's answer)